# SEO for a complete Flex website

Tags: apache-flex, seo

I am planning to build a website completely in Flex. All the contents will be static. No DB will be used. Unfortunately I am not building the website for PUMA or NIKE and so SEO is important. There is an overwhelming and confusing information out there about Flex and SEO.

The following is a piece of information I found on the web

" FLEX( Flash ) uses XML as a primary source of content, and XHTML is just a custom XML. The idea is to to use the HTML pages as XML content for the FLEX( Flash ) application. The XML can be read and indexed by the search engines, and it’s also the ideal content source for your FLEX( Flash ) application.' It goes on to explain how this can be done. Is this really that simple. "

Could someone give some credible links. SEO is important for me.

Comment: If it's important (e.g. not just a hobby), you really should ask the experts.  http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35291

Comment: I voted to close; as there is no actual question here.  Flex excels at building interactive applications; I do not recommend using it for a static web site.  Whatever you read is incorrect.  Most Flex Applications do not use XML as the primary source of context; because the blurb is very confusing.  What does XHTML have to do with XML or Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm really worried about SEO, I'm not building my site using Flex, Flash or Silverlight. A large part of SEO comes from the search engines crawling the content on your site's pages and analyzing the links into and out of your site. When you create a site using Flash or Silverlight, you're making it a lot harder for search engines to crawl your content.

If you're determined to use Flex for your website, I would recommend reading:

- [Revisiting Deep Linking with Flex](http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/06/08/revisiting-deep-linking-with-flex/) from Jonathon Campos's blog
- [How to make your hot new RIA friendly to search engines](http://joshblog.net/2007/08/03/make-your-rich-internet-application-seo-friendly/) from Josh Tynjala
- [Search Engine Optimization Technology Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/seo.html) by Adobe Developer Connection (Lots of resources here)

You'll also want to make your URLs as SEO friendly as possible (ex. http://www.yoursite.com/articles/my-article-about-flex/).

Comment: For deep linking, I recommend you use [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/).  Make sure you also have a sitemap created.  Google is fairly good at crawling Flash.  SEO is really not that bad if you use the html content that you're about to display with in the container you're going to "override" if you're using SWFObject.